All 3 parity drives in my ZFS RAIDZ3 array have failed suddenly in cascade. Would an rsync to my backup array or a rebuild be safer as the next step?
I have an array of 8 drives in a ZFS RAIDZ3. While doing a routine scrub this week I had a sudden and unexpected cascade of 3 drives fail over the course of the operation. This was nearly catastrophic, but the array held. Since I have lost the safety of my parity all at once, I am seeking advice about how to proceed cautiously to preserve my data. I have a second RAID1 mirror that I rsync to periodically, but is out of date. Would it be safer to rsync to this array first before? I want to put the least amount of stress on the degraded array as possible, in case another drive decides to fail. I think that this is the right choice because rsync will only have to copy the data that has changed and not the entire array.
$ zpool status
  pool: backup
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices are faulted in response to persistent errors.
        Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue functioning in a
        degraded state.
action: Replace the faulted device, or use 'zpool clear' to mark the device
        repaired.
  scan: scrub repaired 824K in 23h0m with 0 errors on Mon Sep 16 02:27:06 2024
config:

        NAME                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        backup                                        DEGRADED     0     0     0
          raidz3-0                                    DEGRADED     0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD40EFRX-68WT0N0_WD-WCC4E5PKHHE5  FAULTED     15     0     0  too many errors
            ata-WDC_WD40EFRX-68WT0N0_WD-WCC4E6TYUX25  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD40EFRX-68WT0N0_WD-WCC4EJXKYYU2  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD40EFRX-68WT0N0_WD-WCC4EE1YSFVZ  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD40EFRX-68WT0N0_WD-WCC4E2CDE449  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD40EFRX-68WT0N0_WD-WCC4E2CDER66  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD40EFRX-68WT0N0_WD-WCC4E7HT982J  FAULTED      6     0     0  too many errors
            ata-WDC_WD40EFRX-68WT0N0_WD-WCC4E0PVT451  FAULTED     10     0     0  too many errors

errors: No known data errors


What would be the safest step between these two choices? rsync or a rebuild?
I am also leaning towards rsync, as it will further increase the resiliency during the subsequent rebuild. Because the second array is a RAID1, it would then require three drives to fail (both drives in the RAID1 and another in the RAIDZ3) to lose all of the data during the rebuild, as opposed to one drive during the rebuild or two after the rebuild (I only have a single spare with two more on order).

What is the nature of those failures? Drive read failures according to syslog, dmesg, smartctl? Some external factors (cable, controller, power supply)? If only ZFS sees these errors, memtest? If there are external factors, solve those first; can't recover data with a faulty controller, bad ram etc. Otherwise no good choices there, it could fail either way. If you decide to rsync, preferably without overwriting your existing files (snapshot)...

If you want to be extra careful you could ddrescue each drive first (perhaps buy a 20TB+ drive to do that). Given no read errors, ddrescue does a linear read no seeks, so least amount of stress. However, if ddrescue succeeds, then zfs resilver would likely have worked too; and if ddrescue can't read some things, then zfs will most likely still complain.

@frostschutz I don't see anything from ZFS reported in dmesg. I ran smartctl on all of the drives and they are reported as healthy, although 5 of the  drives report data in the Raw_Read_Error_Rate category, which indicates pre-failure. The failed drives have a value of 2, 4, and 9. However, one of the drives which has not failed in the array is reporting an error rate of 28, multiple times the error rate of the failed drives.
